# MS-SQL Snapshot Isolation and Hibernate behaviour

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hibernate, sql-server-2005

My doubt is relating to the behaviour of Snapshot isolation in SQLserver 2008 and its corresponding configuration in hibernate

[I am referring to the following link](http://blog.grogscave.net/2010/10/using-snapshot-isolation-with-sql.html)

**Step1:** To enable snapshot isolation I have to run the following statements in the database:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

**Step2:** And I set the following property in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!-- Hibernate Isolation Level [READCOMMITED SNAPSHOT ISOLATION]-->    
<property name=”hibernate.connection.isolation”>4096</property>
```

What I have observed is that, when I omit Step2 from the configuration file, the snapshot isolation does not work in my java program.

Since the isolation level is set in the Database, shouldn't it work irrespective of the hibernate configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

because it sets the JDBC transaction isolation level.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/) link:

> (Queries have to do this explicitly– as in run a command ‘SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT’, or have it set in their connection string.)